# How do I make an image property in a winforms user control available in the properties window

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

On a winforms user control I've implemented I'd like to expose a property that allows a user to select an image that will be displayed on that control. I've tried exposing the property as both an Image and a Bitmap, I've tried specifying various attributes that looked promising, but no matter what I do, the property doesn't appear in the Properties window. What I'm looking for is the standard properties window interface that allows you to browse for an image to associate with the property. I suspect I'm going to kick myself for missing something obvious on this one, but I keep drawing a blank!

Comment: It takes one line: public Image Image { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works for me:

```
    private Image image;

    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }
        set
        {
            image = value;
        }
    }
```

After you add the code to the `UserControl`, make sure you rebuild, then the Image property should appear in the Properties window.

Comment: Pretty much verbatim what I have. I think I might create an empty project and do some testing in there. It's currently part of a large solution, so perhaps something is interfering. Thanks for your comment, as at least now I know it should work!

Comment: Well, the same control moved to a new solution works as expected, so it's clearly an issue with the solution. I'll investigate further, but it looks like it was as simple as I expected it to be